# how can I write a dynamic drawable path in android

Tags: android, drawable, setbackground

this is my code and my porpose is clear but it doesn't work. what's the problem?

```
    String sp = "R.drawable.i" + gid;
    int path = Integer.valueOf(sp);

    switch (gid) {
    case 1:
        Layout.setBackgroundResource(path);
        break;
    case 2:
        Layout.setBackgroundResource(path);
    default:
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Context c;String uri = "drawable/i" + gid; int path = c.getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, c.getPackageName());

Comment: Context of ex. your Activity

Comment: @PiotrGolinksi please write your comment as an answer